# mysql : remove row if parent id match in primary key columan

Tags: mysql

I don't know that what should be the title of the question.

I have two table which schema define as below:

**Table 1 (organization_master)**:

```
CREATE TABLE `organization_master` (  `organization_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  `parent_organization_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  `organization_name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,  `c_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
INSERT INTO `organization_master` (`organization_id`, `parent_organization_id`, `organization_name`, `c_user_id`) VALUES
(119, NULL, 'Patel-Apps', 220),
(183, 119, 'Patel-Apps sub 1', 220),
(184, 119, 'Patel-Apps sub 2', 220),
(250, 247, 'Patel-Apps2', 222);
ALTER TABLE `organization_master`  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`organization_id`),  ADD KEY `organization_name` (`organization_name`),  ADD KEY `c_user_id` (`c_user_id`);
ALTER TABLE `organization_master`  MODIFY `organization_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

**Table 2 (organization_assigned_user)** :

```
CREATE TABLE `organization_assigned_user` (  `organization_assigned_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  `organization_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `organization_assigned_user` (`organization_assigned_user_id`, `organization_id`, `user_id`) VALUES (29, 250, 219),(30, 250, 220);
ALTER TABLE `organization_assigned_user`  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`organization_assigned_user_id`),  ADD KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),  ADD KEY `organization_id` (`organization_id`);
ALTER TABLE `organization_assigned_user`  MODIFY `organization_assigned_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=31;
```

When I run below query:

```
SELECT    om.organization_id, 
          om.parent_organization_id, 
          om.organization_name 
FROM      `organization_master` AS om 
LEFT JOIN organization_assigned_user AS oau 
ON        om.organization_id = oau.organization_id 
WHERE     om.c_user_id =220 
OR        oau.user_id =220 
GROUP BY  om.organization_id;
```

It give me output as below:

```
organization_id parent_organization_id  organization_name
119             NULL                    Patel-Apps
183             119                     Patel-Apps sub 1
184             119                     Patel-Apps sub 2
250             247                     Patel-Apps2
```

Now, my question is that I don't want the rows which parent_organization_id exists in organization_id column. i.e 199 parent_organization_id  exists in organization_id. so my out put should be like like below:

```
organization_id parent_organization_id  organization_name
119             NULL                    Patel-Apps
250             247                     Patel-Apps2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.organization_id,
    a.parent_organization_id,
    a.organization_name
FROM (
    SELECT om.organization_id , 
            om.parent_organization_id, 
            om.organization_name 
    FROM `organization_master` AS om 
    LEFT JOIN organization_assigned_user AS oau ON om.organization_id = oau.organization_id 
    WHERE om.c_user_id =220 OR oau.user_id =220 
    GROUP BY om.organization_id
) a 
WHERE a.parent_organization_id NOT IN
(
    SELECT om.organization_id
    FROM `organization_master` AS om 
    LEFT JOIN organization_assigned_user AS oau ON om.organization_id = oau.organization_id 
    WHERE om.c_user_id =220 OR oau.user_id =220 
    GROUP BY om.organization_id
)
OR a.parent_organization_id IS NULL
```

If this works for you, consider storing results of your main `SELECT` (used twice in my reply) in a TEMP table and joining on that for performance purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Using your own query:

```
SELECT    om.organization_id, 
          om.parent_organization_id, 
          om.organization_name 
FROM      organization_master AS om 
LEFT JOIN organization_assigned_user AS oau 
ON        om.organization_id = oau.organization_id 
WHERE     (om.c_user_id = 220 
           OR 
           oau.user_id = 220)

AND       (om.parent_organization_id NOT IN (SELECT   om1.organization_id
                                            FROM      organization_master AS om1
                                            LEFT JOIN organization_assigned_user AS oau1
                                            ON        om1.organization_id = oau1.organization_id
                                            WHERE     om1.c_user_id = om.c_user_id
                                            OR        oau1.user_id = oau.user_id)
           OR
           om.parent_organization_id IS NULL)

GROUP BY  om.organization_id
;
```

I've used a subquery to get all `organization_id` of your main query:

```
SELECT    om1.parent_organization_id
FROM      organization_master AS om1
LEFT JOIN organization_assigned_user AS oau1
ON        om1.organization_id = oau1.organization_id
WHERE     om1.c_user_id = 220
OR        oau1.user_id = 220;

| parent_organization_id |
|------------------------|
| 247                    |
| NULL                   |
| 119                    |
| 119                    |
```

As you can see, it returns a NULL row, hence you must take care of this row by adding another condition on your WHERE clause:

```
AND       (om.parent_organization_id NOT IN (SELECT   om1.organization_id
                                            FROM      organization_master AS om1
                                            LEFT JOIN organization_assigned_user AS oau1
                                            ON        om1.organization_id = oau1.organization_id
                                            WHERE     om1.c_user_id = om.c_user_id
                                            OR        oau1.user_id = oau.user_id)
           OR
           om.parent_organization_id IS NULL)
```

This is the final result:

```
| organization_id | parent_organization_id | organization_name |
|-----------------|------------------------|-------------------|
| 119             | NULL                   | Patel-Apps        |
| 250             | 247                    | Patel-Apps2       |
```

Check it here: http://rextester.com/UWSG42619